# Как в декораторе в typescript вывести параметры методов

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Type<T>{
    [key:string]:T
}



function log(target:any,methodname:string,descriptor?:string){
    console.log(`method ${methodname}`);
}


class myMap<T>{
    private map:Array<string|number>=[];

    public @log setItem( key:string,item:string|number){
        this.map[key]=item;
        console.log(`Item is setted`);
    }


    public @log getItem( key:string){
        return `Selected item is ${this.map[key]}`;
    }

    public @log clean(){
        this.map=[];
        console.log(`Map is empty`);
    }

    public @log printMap(){

        console.log(`Map consist of next elements: `);
        for(let key in this.map){
            console.log(`${this.map[key]}`);
        }
    }

}

let mymap = new myMap<string|number>();
mymap.setItem('name','Dmitri');
mymap.setItem('age',22);
console.log(mymap.getItem('name'));
mymap.printMap();
mymap.clean();
```

Comment: имеются ввиду значения с которыми была вызвана декорируемая функция? или имена параметров типа  _key_, _item_?

Comment: [TypeScript 2.8 adds several predefined conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types). да, по поводу вашего кода: где попытка использовать интерфейс `Type`

Comment: @qwabra, как ссылка связана с вопросом?

Comment: @Grundy имена параметров, но хотелось бы знать как сделать и то и другое

Comment: Можешь привести пример какой вывод ты ожидаешь для кода в вопросе?

Answer (score -1):

имена параметров(ключи) должны быть известны заранее

```
// /*
{
    let myMap = function <M>() {
        let map: any = {} // как спрятать
        class myMap<M>{
            // private map: M // на сегодняшний день private не прячет
            setItem(key: keyof M,item: M[keyof M]) {
                map[key] = item
                console.log(`Item is setted`)
            }
            getItem(key: keyof M) {
                return `Selected item is ${map[key]}`
            }
            clean() {
                map = {}
                console.log(`Map is empty`)
            }
            printMap() {
                console.log(`Map consist of next elements: `)
                for (let key in map) {
                    console.log(`${map[key]}`)
                }
            }
        }
        return new myMap<M>()
    }
    interface M {
        qwa: string,
        bra: number,
    }
    let mymap = myMap<M>()
    mymap.setItem('qwa','Dmitri')
    mymap.setItem('bra',22)
    // mymap.setItem('bra','22') // <-- not err
    console.log(mymap.getItem('bra'))
    mymap.printMap()
    mymap.clean()

    mymap.setItem('bra',22)
    console.log(mymap.getItem('bra'))
    mymap.printMap()

}// */
```

---

```
// /*
{
    function myMap<O>(_obj: O) {
        type p = {
            clean(): void,
            printMap(): void,
        };
        let map = {}

        //@ts-ignore
        if (!_obj.__proto__) _obj.__proto__ = {}
        let keys = Object.keys(_obj)
        //@ts-ignore
        Object.defineProperty(_obj.__proto__,'clean',{
            enumerable: false,
            value() {
                init()
                console.log(`Map is empty`)
            }
        })
        //@ts-ignore
        Object.defineProperty(_obj.__proto__,'printMap',{
            enumerable: false,
            value() {
                console.log(`Map consist of next elements: `)
                for (let key in map) {
                    console.log(`${map[key]}`)
                }
            }
        })
        function init() {
            map = {}
            keys.forEach(_key => {
                Object.defineProperty(_obj,_key,{
                    set(_val) {
                        map[_key] = _val
                        console.log(`Item is setted`)
                    },
                    get() {
                        return `Selected item is ${map[_key]}`
                    }
                })
            })
        }
        init()
        return <O & p>_obj
    }
    let mymap = myMap({
        qwa: <String>null,
        bra: <Number>null,
    })
    mymap.qwa = 'Dmitri'
    mymap.bra = 22
    // map.bra = '22' // <-- err
    console.log(mymap.bra)
    mymap.printMap()
    mymap.clean()

    mymap.bra = 22
    mymap.printMap()
}
// */
```